# How do I fix my partitions

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, gparted, ext4, disk-management

I want to remove `sda1` and allocate all the space to `sda4` including the unallocated space. Can I do this somehow using commands without having to reinstall Ubuntu?

[image: GParted screenshot]

Comment: do you have any other OS installed on your pc? Or is it just the Ubuntu? Do you ave any other drives installed on your PC? Update the question with answers to these questions.

Comment: no other OS installed

Comment: then I would suggest you to backup all the data and clean install Ubuntu. Remember to clear all the partitions when in live boot.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need commands. You can do all this with gparted. However, the operation you are looking for involves moving partitions. That will take a long time, and there is a serious chance that it does not succeed correctly.

It would be less painfull with better change on success to

- Make sure your backup of `sda2` is up to date
- Delete `sda1` and `sda2`
- Create a new partition in the available space (former sda1, sda2 and unallocated space)
- Place the data back on your now much larger data partition.

This way, you do not touch the system itself.

Comment: sda2 seems to be an external disk so could be disconnected.

Comment: @Rinzwind all are partitions on the same disk sda.

Comment: They are all on the same disk.

Comment: risking to sound dumb.......If I back up sd4 on an external and then reformat the whole disk how do I then copy sd4 back to the empty partition without an OS? I want to avoid having to reinstall ubuntu once again if possible

Comment: Must be possible to do this but you will need to work at a low level and have sufficient technical skills to bring it all back together. Reinstalling Ubuntu takes 15 minutes. If you live with a separate data partition (which you could mount permanently), then you do not even need to reinstall. Nothing prevents you from attempting a move sda4 to the front, but then you will also need to repair your booting. It is all possible, but difficulty differs.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer (check the green mark) if it helped you.